# Stop all flash animations when window/tab is not focused

Tags: javascript, performance, flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking for a code to stop all flash animations on a web page when this page/tab is not focused or active. Because this problem causes performance loss at any computer.

Any solutions with As3 or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to stop them all, but it is harder to resume them afterwards depending on how your code is organized, use this function to stop all movie clips:

```
function stopEverything(disp : DisplayObjectContainer) : void
{
    if(disp is MovieClip)
    {
        MovieClip(disp).stop();
    }
    for(var i : int = 0; i < disp.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var child : DisplayObject = disp.getChildAt(i);
        if(child is DisplayObjectContainer)
        {
            stopEverything(DisplayObjectContainer(child));
        }
    }
}
```

Then to stop all objects you would do: `stopEverything(stage);`.

Note that this is only stopping MovieClip animations, all EnterFrame events will still be called.

Another smart option is to verify that the application lost focus and then do `stage.frameRate = 1;`, and once focus is gained again you can set it back to what it was.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, lostFocus);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, gainedFocus);

function lostFocus(e:Event):void
{
    stage.frameRate = 1;
}

function gainedFocus(e:Event):void
{
    stage.frameRate = 24; // or whatever it should be
}
```